# :after content on a display: none div returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I have two plugins, one is a GridSystem which can be found here: http://ebleir.i234.me:93/Loai%20Aptana/assets/js/grid-system.js and the other one is Tabs function which can be found on line 90 here: http://ebleir.i234.me:93/Loai%20Aptana/assets/js/main.js

When I place the grid system inside a tab, the grid system stop working and show this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

After two days of dubbing, I found the problem, it is a Chrome/Safari bug...  Here is all about it here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236603

Note, this works everywhere but Chrome and Safari.

Please, is there anything I can do to make it work? is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Please provide example on jsfiddle

Comment: I have put one togther: http://jsfiddle.net/HTHf5/1/